# Decrypting AES in AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We are using below php code to encrypt value 'John' using AES encryption and the encryption value that's getting generated for it is - 'SYKRYFHeCijBb8SSJiPxaw=='.

When I am trying to decrypt this value using below function in a cloudpage, its not working.
Is it possible to decrypt the SSL encrypted value in SFMC.

PHP code:

```
<?php $daata='John'; 
$password = '11111111111111111111111111111111'; 
$iv='1111111111111111'; 
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, 'AES-256-CBC', $password, 0, $iv); 
echo $encrypted ; ?>
```

AMPscript

```
%%[  set @decData =DecryptSymmetric('SYKRYFHeCijBb8SSJiPxaw==', 'AES', @null, '11111111111111111111111111111111', @NULL, '0', @NULL, '1111111111111111' )   
set @base64Decoded = base64Decode(@decData) ]%% 
%%=v(@decData)=%% 
%%=v(@base64Decoded )=%%
```

Answer (score 1):

The encryption/decryption in Marketing Cloud is slightly different and uses a propriatory method than the implementation used elsewhere. The best (easiest) bet here is to use the (Encrypt/Decrypt)Symmetric function in a cloud page and manage your data like a REST endpoint through that.